# meteor call to method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  newMessage: function (message, channel) {
    message.timestamp = Date.now();
    message.user = Meteor.userId();
    message.channel = channel;
    Messages.insert(message);
  }
})
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
Meteor.call('newMessage', {
    text: $('.input-box_text').val(),
    channel: Session.get('channel')
});
alert(Session.get('channel')); // alert's general
```

It inserts a new document but channel is null. Why?

Comment: Have you already add a breakpoint in the newMessage : `message.channel = channel;` to see the channel value?

Comment: I'm just stupid. The call is sending just 1 variable as object, so in method there should be just one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what are you expecting from that, but you should call the method like this:

```
Meteor.call('newMessage',
   $('.input-box_text').val(),
   Session.get('channel') 
);
```

Comment: Yes, but I was sending it as object and I didn't know that. Though it's syntax for more parameters.